# C won't compile with sdl.h included

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to get SDL library working on my macbook to write a small game(probably tetris) in c.
I read and followed the installation instructions for SDL at https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation.

However, when I tried to compile the following c code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    printf("Window Initialization!\n");
    SDL_Window *window;
    //printf("SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED is %d\n", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
                             "SDL2 Test",   
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              640, 480, 0);
    if(window == NULL){
        printf("Creation of Window Failed\n");
        SDL_Quit();
        return -1;
    }
    SDL_Delay(3000);    //delay for 3000 ms
    SDL_Renderer* rend = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

with the command:

```
gcc main.c -o run
```

The following error is printed:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_SDL_CreateWindow", referenced from:
  _main in sdl1-a80c27.o
"_SDL_Delay", referenced from:
  _main in sdl1-a80c27.o
"_SDL_DestroyWindow", referenced from:
  _main in sdl1-a80c27.o
"_SDL_Init", referenced from:
  _main in sdl1-a80c27.o
"_SDL_Quit", referenced from:
  _main in sdl1-a80c27.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Since I did make and sudo make install, according to the website, the SDL should be "universal" now. So I assume I would not need linker. But apparently that is not the case.

Previously I also tried to just add framework file into /Library/Frameworks. And then if I did:

```
gcc sdl1.c -o run -F/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -framework SDL2
```

The code can get compiled. However, sometimes I want to include SDL2_image.h as well and adding another -F/.../ won't work.

I would really appreciate any suggestions/advice. Thanks!

Comment: You need to compile with `-lSDL` probably.

Comment: To get the flag just use `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation

```
gcc sdl1.c -o run `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
```

sdl comes with a tool to generate for you all the flags, just use it, it is the best way to maintain your build system.